# How to link Visual Studio to SQL Server?

Tags: c#

I am making a project in which I need to connect to sql server. For this purpose, I have installed sql server configuration manager and sql management studio but link is not being made.I could not understand that where is the problem.

Here, when I am using management studio , and write my pc name, again I could not connect to server.

Comment: First try link with your database using `ADO.NET` and check is your connection string working good ?

Comment: what efforts taken ?

Comment: You must know the sql-servers-Name (or is it a local one ?) - what are you trying to acheive? selecting some data from SQL in your application? how complex? We need more information - there are many ways to talk with SQL in .net

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio command prompt and then type : `sqlcmd -L` this will show servers available.

Use the servername and connect with the server with credentials if set already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the connection within Visual studio(if server is installed) it self.

Here are the steps.

1.Open server explorer.

2.Right click on Data Connections

3.Select Add connection.(A new window will popup)

4.Type the server name(localhost\sqlexpress by default)

5.Give a database name and click OK.

You are done !!!.